# Difference between "change is constant" and "change is a constant"

Tags: word-choice, differences, indefinite-articles

The boss asked me the other day whether it's more correct to say

> In our business, change is constant.

or

> In our business, change is a constant.

Both of these sound perfectly correct to me, which is what I told him; but there's a slight difference in meaning that I just can't seem to articulate. Help?

[Definitions](http://freedictionary.org/?Query=constant&button=Search), not that they're much help:

> **constant** (noun): a quantity that does not vary
>   **constant** (adjective): unvarying in nature; steadfast in purpose or devotion or affection; uninterrupted in time and indefinitely long continuing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if your implication is that *change* is a given, that it is one of the *only* constants you see in the business, then you use the noun (change is a constant).

If your implication is that all we ever see is change, change, change, change, change then use the adjective (change is constant).

Comment: Your distinction between change being one of the *only* constants vs. change being continuous really helped me figure this out. Hopefully, I'll be able to explain it to the boss semi-coherently now.

Answer (score 6):

"Change is constant" means that change is occurring continuously, while "change is a constant" means that change is an always-to-be-expected condition.  The choice between the two terms thus depends on context and what you want to emphasize.  For example, if discussing company flexibility, I think one might say "We recognize that change is a constant in this business" (or perhaps rather "We recognize that change is a given in this business").

Comment: When heard in isolation both phrases mean essentially the same thing to me. It's the context you provide which makes the difference. +1

Answer (score 0):

I believe you already understood the first one "Change is constant" but the second one "change is a constant" simply means that the only thing that is constant is "change" itself, which must be. So they are pretty much the same thing. "Constant" a situation that does not change (e.g. Change which must occur and still remain change itself).